# Mongoose problem: schema not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Hey guys,
I've been trying to play with mongoose & node, but I have some problem regarding even the simplest run...
I have this code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/db');

var User = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    index: { unique: true }
  },
  name: String,
  lastseen: Date,
  isonline: Boolean,
  hashed_password: String,
  salt: String
});

mongoose.model('User', User);

var User = db.model('User');

var u = new User();
u.name = 'Foo';

u.save(function() {
    User.find().all(function(arr) {
        console.log(arr);
        console.log('length='+arr.length);
    });
});
```

Which should run, since it's an example code... but I have this error:

```
node.js:181
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
ReferenceError: Schema is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (myfile.js:12:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:420:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:426:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:336:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:297:12)
    at Array.<anonymous> (module.js:439:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:173:26)
```

Does anyone of you know what's wrong with this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of mongoose are you using?

I ran into similar problems with mongoose < 1.1.0 which updating cured.

Comment: I'm using 1.1 now, anyhow I think I had that problem :). I simply killed everything and restarted the project.